# Finding the equation of a curve of a numerical curve

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I have a 2D plot and it seems quadratic. I got it from a data set which is obtained numerically from a calculation. i know the equation can be obtained by fitting the data sets. It seems Python automatically fitted from the data points. I need to print the equation of the fitted curve.

I solved Y for different X and obtained two arreys Y and X. Then I plotted them

```
plt.plot(X,Y)

plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.savefig('YvsX.png', format='png', dpi=1000)

plt.show()
```

and obtained this:

[image]

Need to print the equation of this plot

Comment: Check out `numpy.polyfit`.

Comment: Your graph does not look quadratic--it looks more like hyperbolic (y = c / x) or perhaps logarithmic (y = - c * log(x)). Do you want to fit one of those curves? Why do you think that "Python automatically fitted from the data points"? Isn't that just a plot of the data you provided? Or does the graph look too smooth? Just how did you "solve Y for different X"? Could you provide the data you used for the plot?

Comment: @RoryDaulton I extracted data from the plot for fitting, see my answer to this question.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Y is function of X and X is the denominator in a array of vibrational frequency values for a molecular system. if there is one frequency then it is simple exponential relation. but for more than one vibrational modes the formula is a multiple of all exponential. like for 63 vibrational modes of a molecular system the formula is (exp(f1/2X)/(1-exp(f1/X)))*(exp(f2/2X)/(1-exp(f2/X)))*......*(exp(f63/2X)/(1-exp(f63/X))) and then ratio for two different molecular systems. 

i solved Y for a range of X and got two array for Y and X which i plotted and got a smooth curve. i need the eq

Comment: ...so that's the equation then, right? The data is coming from an equation and now you want the equation of the equation? What am I missing?

Comment: @mikuszefski that is correct. In the original and very complex equation i inserted numerical fixed values for some parameters and it simplifies and gives this simple plot. Although you are right that i can simplify the equation directly by putting those parameter values but original equation is too big to handle analytically.

Comment: So you have a very complicated analytical solution and you want an empiric analytical approximation...as provided by @JamesPhillips correct?

Answer (score 5):

I extracted data points from your plot and performed an equation search, which turned up "y = a * exp(b/x) + Offset" as a likely candidate equation. Here is a graphical fitter using the extracted data and this equation, with initial parameter estimates for scipy's curve_fit() solver provided by scipy's differential_evolution genetic algorithm module. That module uses the Latin Hypercube algorithm to ensure a thorough search of parameter space, requiring bounds within which to search. In this example I used bounds of the maximum and minimum data values, and those search bounds worked well in this case.

[image: plot]

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import warnings


# extracted from plot
xData = numpy.array([365.731, 377.548, 392.909, 409.453, 428.360, 447.267, 473.264, 498.079, 521.713, 545.347, 573.707, 598.522, 629.246, 669.423, 695.420, 736.779, 772.230, 823.042, 858.493, 883.308, 915.214, 951.846, 986.115, 1029.837, 1059.379, 1105.465, 1155.096, 1204.726, 1251.994])
yData = numpy.array([-0.306, -0.576, -0.969, -1.276, -1.766, -2.147, -2.503, -2.883, -3.177, -3.398, -3.705, -3.963, -4.196, -4.515, -4.662, -4.871, -5.055, -5.300, -5.374, -5.496, -5.582, -5.705, -5.803, -5.914, -5.987, -6.098, -6.208, -6.331, -6.368])


def func(x, a, b, Offset): # from the zunzun.com "function finder"
    return a * numpy.exp(b/x) + Offset


# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
    return numpy.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)


def generate_Initial_Parameters():
    # min and max used for bounds
    maxX = max(xData)
    minX = min(xData)
    maxY = max(yData)
    minY = min(yData)

    minData = min(minX, minY)
    maxData = max(maxX, maxY)

    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([minData, maxData]) # search bounds for a
    parameterBounds.append([minData, maxData]) # search bounds for b
    parameterBounds.append([minData, maxData]) # search bounds for Offset

    # "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x

# by default, differential_evolution completes by calling curve_fit() using parameter bounds
geneticParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

# now call curve_fit without passing bounds from the genetic algorithm,
# just in case the best fit parameters are aoutside those bounds
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters)
print('Fitted parameters:', fittedParameters)
print()

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print()
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: thank you for your through reply. in this line 

    def func(x, a, b, Offset): # from the zunzun.com "function finder"
    return a * numpy.exp(b/x) + Offset
did you took/assume the function exp(b/x) and then found the optimized parameters(b and offset) by minimizing the sum of square error? 

I was looking for finding the equation of a smooth curve without extracting the data points.

Comment: I have a Python semi-automated data point extractor for just this purpose, as sometimes people post a scatterplot (or in this case a line plot) without the data. For the purpose of equation search from a line plot as was done here, I needed to extract enough data points to well follow the shape of the curve. I then ran those through my zunzun.com "function finder", looking for equations with three or less parameters - of all the equations returned by the search, this equation seemed like a good candidate. I pasted this equation and the extracted data into an example fitter, and I was done.

Answer (score 2):

I give you an example of how to find a quadratic fit:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
points = np.array([(0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 6), (3, 11),(4,18),(5,27)])
# get x and y vectors
x = points[:,0]
y = points[:,1]

# calculate polynomial
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)
z
```

Out:

```
array([1.0000000e+00, 4.2765887e-15, 2.0000000e+00])
```

which implies x ** 2 + 4.2765887e-15 * x +2

Comment: Hi..  thank you for reply. I saw this method in other places in this forum. Thank you for clarifying it further. I was asking if it is possible to get the equation of a smooth curve without extracting the data points.